# Criterion for etaleness

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $A \rightarrow B$ is an inclusion of commutative rings which is finite, so that $B$ is generated as an $A$-module by elements $ b_1, \ldots, b_n$ say.

Are there any algebraic conditions on the $b_i$ one can impose which will ensure this extension is etale?

I know there are conditions such as the Jacobian Criterion, but it's not clear to me if this should simplify in the above context or not. Any comments appreciated.

Comment: How much additional constraints are you willing to empose on your rings $A$ and $B$? Can they be Noetherian by any chance? Or even finitely generated $\Bbbk$-algebras over an algebraically closed field? Alright, I might be asking for a lot there. But still, anything beyond commutative?

Comment: I'm very happy to assume that $A$ and $B$ are both Noetherian and of finite type over a field. It'd be nice to avoid assuming the field is algebraically closed, but I'd be happy for something under that assumption too.